# Task assignment and status UI

Tags: gui-design, data-collection

I am trying to understand what could be the most optimal solution for auto work assignment UI to 250 users basis below parameters:

- Attendance
- Skill
- Type
- Value (Low/Medium/High)

The status feature on UI should consist of # of tasks assigned to each user on daily/weekly/monthly & yearly basis.

The UI should consist of re-assignment functionality

Please feel free to suggest if anything else that can be useful to show on such UI with basic framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

For example

**Task A** (Importance: 500, Category: II)

**Task B** (Importance: 200, Category I)

Users:

**User A** - Attendance: 50, Skill: 14, Categories: I,III, Value: Low

**User B** - Attendance: 250, Skill: 5, Categories: I,III, Value: Medium

**User C** - Attendance: 175, Skill: 14, Categories: II, Value: Medium

This system should be build on conditions and criterias:

1. The **user** can only get tasks from his **category**

(so, user B and A fall of at start) - The **Task A** is automatically assigned to **User C**)

2. **More important tasks** are first of all dedicated to people with greater **skill**

(so, user C, haven't category I for **Task B** - so B and A remains, due to the higher skill of user A - he gets this task.)

it all depends on the conditions and criteria you define. The possibillities are many - however, it is worth limiting everything to a minimum first.

---

The main question is whether the tasks are to be assigned by a **competent person** or **automatically**?

I think the **type** should be the same as the task **category**.

Based on what is the user value to be measured? - I suggest a wider scale **1-10** - instead of **Low - Medium - High**, calculated on the basis of skill, attendance (calculated using the number of completed tasks).

Going a bit further into **psychology** - performing tasks should give **satisfaction** and **gratification**  - you may want to consider **gamification** and adding categories of tasks in which users feel best

- Motivation
- Prize
- The importance (of task)

Based on what is the **user skill** to be measured?

---

It is important to remember that each parameter must be logically and contextually connected in some way.

E.g Attendance with the number of tasks performed in time (so you need to collect this data to calculate the next)

---

In the context of soft management, it is impossible to categorize people in this way. usually one PM, allocates tasks based on their knowledge of the team.

---

As far as interface design is concerned - this is a complex task:

Scopes to consider:

- Creating Tasks
- Asigning Tasks
- Display Users (lists)
- CRUD Tasks
- Acomplishing tasks

[image]

---

Comment: Zak: The assignment is rule based automatic.

Comment: It's a more complicated mission - everything should be based on numbers and mathematics then.

Comment: Zak: Agreed, I just wanted to understand the approach of the numbers and mathematics :)

Comment: ok, edited for your purposes